# how to input an array from excel cell in python?

Tags: python, pandas, excel

I want to read an excel file using python and pandas. However, one of the cell entry is an array  (or list) like [1,2,3]. The other cell in that column can be numbers. My question is how to input that array (or list) from the cell using Python?

Thank you.

Comment: This question is too vague, but maybe you would be interested in learning the [xlwings](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/working-with-excel-files-in-python-using-xlwings/) module. That lets you get the values of specific cells in a sheet without loading an entire dataframe

Comment: Load everything as string then run `ast.literal_eval` on it. *Make sure that your data cannot be manipulated to allow something like arbitrary code execution.*

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.